# Discrete fourier transform giving complex conjugate of "right" answer

Tags: python, fft, complex-numbers

I'm attempting to implement a simple version of the discrete fourier transform in python.
My code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cmath
def dft_simple(sequence):
# dft of seq defined as
# sigma from n=0 to N-1 of x(n) *exp(-2*pi*j*k*n/N)
  seqLenth = len(sequence)
  complexSequence = []
  for k in range(seqLenth):
    sigma = 0 - 0j
    print("k = {}".format(k))
    for n in range(seqLenth):
      print("n = {}".format(n))
      print("value = {}".format(sequence[n] * cmath.exp(-2*1j * cmath.pi * float(k) \
                                    * float(n)  / float(seqLenth))))
      sigma = sigma + (sequence[n] * cmath.exp(-2*1j * cmath.pi * float(k) \
                                    * float(n)  / float(seqLenth)))
      print("exp = {0}".format(-2*1j * cmath.pi * float(k) \
                                    * float(n)  / float(seqLenth)))
    complexSequence.append(sigma)

    print("sum = {}".format(sigma))
    print("")
  return(complexSequence)
seq4 = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]
print(dft_simple(seq4))
```

I receive a result of:

```
[(4+0j), (1-2.414213562373095j), (-1.8369701987210297e-16-2.220446049250313e-16j), (1-0.4142135623730949j), -2.449293598294706e-16j, (0.9999999999999992+0.4142135623730959j), (3.2904645469127765e-16-3.3306690738754696e-16j), (0.9999999999999997+2.4142135623730954j)]
```

This differs from the answer I get on wolfram alpha when calculating the DFT of the same sequence [here,](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=discrete%20fourier%20transform%20of(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)) in two ways. First, wolfram alpha is dividing by sqrt(N), where N is the length of the sequence, which is just a different symmetric definition of the forward and inverse transforms.
Secondly, and more confusingly, my implementation is giving me the complex conjugate of the result wolfram alpha is giving me - the numeric values are otherwise approximately the same. Is this an issue of an implementation problem on my code(e.g. syntax error), or is it simply wolfram using a different definition of the discrete fourier transform?

Comment: [Wolfram uses a different definition of the discrete fourier transform](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FourierTransforms.htmlhttps://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FourierTransforms.html#19751)

Comment: @SleuthEye Fixed your link: [Wolfram uses a different definition of DFT](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FourierTransforms.html#19751)

Comment: Ah, okay, this makes more sense - I previously was using [wolfram math world](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteFourierTransform.html) as a reference, thank you for  clearing that up. Could you leave that as an answer so I can mark this question as resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases (for the scaling and for the complex conjugated result), the underlying cause is the difference in the definition used for the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT).

The [default definition of the DFT from Wolfram](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FourierTransforms.html#19751) uses the formula:

[image: \frac{1}{n^{1/2}}\sum_{r=1}^n u_r e^{2\pi i (r-1)(s-1)/n}]

Or equivalently using zero based indexing, time index `n`, frequency index `k` and `j=sqrt(-1)` to compare against your implementation:

[image: \frac{1}{N^{1/2}}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} u_n e^{2\pi j k n/N}]

Your implementation uses what Wolfram refers to as the "signal processing" convention:

[image: \sum_{r=1}^n u_r e^{-2\pi i (r-1)(s-1)/n}]

which again is equivalent to:

[image: \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} u_n e^{-2\pi j k n/N}]

For real-valued input sequences, using a negative sign in the complex exponential term would produce a result that is the complex conjugate of the similar expression which uses a positive sign in the complex exponential term (and vice versa):

[image: \begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} u_n e^{-2\pi j k n/N}&= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} u_n \mbox{conjugate}(e^{2\pi j k n/N}) \ &= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \mbox{conjugate}(u_n e^{2\pi j k n/N}) &,\mbox{for real $u_n$}\ &= \mbox{conjugate}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} u_n e^{2\pi j k n/N}\right) &,\mbox{for real $u_n$}\\end{align}]